# Problem rearranging a surd equation (Sallen & Key Sensitivity Derivative Manipulation)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This has relation to some electrical engineering principles (Sallen & Key filter sensitivity calculation)

$$\omega_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1R_3C_2C_4}}$$

$$S_{R1}^Q=-\frac{1}{2}-\left[-\frac{1}{R_1^2C_2}\right]\cdot\frac{R_1Q}{\omega_n}$$

This is stated to equal

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\sqrt{\frac{R_3C_4}{R_1C_2}}\label{1}\tag{1}$$

But when I rearrange it I get

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\sqrt{\frac{R_3C_4}{R_1C_2}}\cdot\frac{1}{(R_1C_2)(R_3C_4)}$$

Clearly I'm making a mistake but I can't see why,

Can someone provide a step by step to get the desired form \ref{1}

$$-\frac{1}{2}+Q\frac{R_1}{R1^2C_2}\cdot\frac{1}{\omega_n}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\frac{1}{R_1C_2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1C_2}\sqrt{R_3C_4}}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\frac{\sqrt{R_3C_4}}{R_1C_2}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{R_1C_2}(R_3C_4)}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\sqrt{\frac{R_3C_4}{R_1C_2}}\cdot\frac{1}{(R_1C_2)(R_3C_4)}$$

Comment: You got the $\frac{1}{\omega_n}$ factor reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I had a mistake with a fraction, 1 over omega being all numerator and a denominator of 1, I had it inverted.

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\frac{1}{R_1C_2}\cdot{\sqrt{R_1C_2}\sqrt{R_3C_4}}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\frac{\sqrt{R_1C_2}}{R_1C_2}\cdot{\frac{\sqrt{R_1C_2}}{\sqrt{R_1C_2}}\sqrt{R_3C_4}}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\frac{\sqrt{R_3C_4}}{\sqrt{R_1C_2}}$$

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\sqrt{\frac{R_3C_4}{R_1C_2}}$$

An identical option is to take my deleterious

$$=-\frac{1}{2}+Q\sqrt{\frac{R_3C_4}{R_1C_2}}\cdot\frac{1}{(R_1C_2)(R_3C_4)}$$

and multiple by

$$\frac{1}{\omega_n^2}$$